# Recruiter asked what is my motivation

Tags: communication, recruitment

*Disclaimer: English is not my mother tongue and I have trouble understanding what this recruiter needs.*

I've got a recruiter that contacted me about role X. I looked up the Careers page of the company and saw role Y which I considered could be better for me because of my experience. So he sent me a message via LinkedIn saying:

> Please send me your CV and motivation for the role Y

What is he expecting exactly? Any examples would be useful.

Comment: The recruiter wants your explanation of why you think Role Y would be a good fit for you. Your CV is simply your work history or résumé.

Comment: Thanks @KentA. do you think I should send it inline with my response or as a separate document?

Comment: I would send it as a separate document. As the answers that have been provided already recommend, you could provide your explanation in the form of a cover letter for your CV. This way, whether or not the recruiter is asking for a cover letter (I'm not convinced he  is), he will still get your explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The recruiter is most likely asking for a motivation letter, otherwise known as a covering letter to go with your CV. There are  several resources online that you can use for writing one, [here is one example](https://resumegenius.com/cover-letters-the-how-to-guide). And to quote them:

> A cover letter is a one page document that you send with your resume
>   when applying for a job. It is meant to: Introduce yourself to the
>   hiring manager. Argue why you'd be a good fit for the job.

[You can also find plenty more examples elsewhere](https://www.google.lu/search?q=how%20to%20write%20a%20motivation%20letter)

Though if you're not sure and want clarification, ask the recruiter to be more clear in what they want. There is no harm in asking for a clarification